# Render html from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

How do I store html in that when I write that html to the browser, it ends up being rendered as html and not literal text?

Example how do I make this render a link?  This would be a property in my json for example:

```
"pastCompanies": [ "Pivotal", "Microsoft", "<a href=\"https:\//www.linkedin.com\/in\/someperson\" target=\"_blank\">...</a>"],
```

so how do I get this to render a tag: `"<a href=\"https:\//www.linkedin.com\/in\/someperson\" target=\"_blank\">...</a>"`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better design to just return the link and not the entire HTML element?

Comment: yea but the only problem is in this context for this particular set of data, I don't know which could be links...like that array isn't always going to necessarily have a link in the last item in the array

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but you could, when looping through the array to display the data, detect if an element is a link with a regex, then return it wrapped in the correct html.

Comment: @Namrehs that sounds like a lot of extra unnecessary work.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't like to mix data with html/display elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery example, just use `htlm` function http://api.jquery.com/html/

JS you can use `innerHTML` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

```
var obj = {"pastCompanies": [ "Pivotal", "Microsoft", "<a href=\"https:\//www.linkedin.com\/in\/someperson\" target=\"_blank\">...</a>"]};

//JQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#one').html(obj.pastCompanies[2]);
});
//JS
document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/633xfL9v/2/

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape